# Clean allocation and construction of one object with the standard C++98/03

Tags: c++

In my code I need to allocate and construct an object dynamically and push the pointer to it into a vector. Is there a cleaner way to this than the code below without using all those ugly try-catch blocks? I cannot use non-standard libraries. There is no C++11. I only have the standard C++98/03.

```
void insert() {
            //...do something...
            MyType* obj = 0;
            try {
                obj = alloc.allocate(1); // yes, even the allocation must be inside one try-catch in my case, since I need to undo something
                alloc.construct(obj, default_obj);
                try {
                    v.push_back(obj);
                } catch (...) {
                    alloc.destroy(obj);
                    throw;
                }
            } catch (...) {
                //..undo something..
                if (obj)
                    alloc.deallocate(obj, 1);
                throw;
            }
}
```

EDIT:
alloc is an allocator passed as argument somewhere to avoid raw new/delete. v is a vector.

Comment: What is alloc.consturct and alloc.dealloc why not use new and delete?

Comment: alloc is an allocator having the standard interface. It's used to avoid raw new and delete. v is a std::vector

Comment: I see, you are making your on container, in that case make a custom RAII container that deals with allocator, look at std::unique_ptr for a reference: you should be able to get it down to a single try catch with no destruction code.

Comment: Did you write the code for alloc?  Why avoid new and delete?

Comment: @DavidGrayson As I said, the allocator is passed as argument somewhere before. It does not matter where for my problem. No I cannot use new and delete.

Comment: @Martin: He said _for a reference_.

Comment: @Martin: yes but RAII is still on the cards and unique_ptr is the bast implementation of a basic RAII wrapper.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: the use of allocators to control whete objects are allocate is a legitimate use casr. The global allocation functions just don't cut it e.g. when allocating in different threads, allocation objects of wide varying size, and in a number of other use cases.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Using custom allocators is fine. Mangling up your program with this non-RAII mess is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And yet, every time you `#include<vector>`, you're getting code very much like this. But I don't see you complaining about it. If he's writing a container, that means RAII isn't going to be helpful. Answer the actual question or don't; your snide remarks about how "silly" the question is isn't helping.

Comment: @Nicol: I can complain about `vector` if you like, but that's not what this question is about. And I'll thank you not to shoot orders and insults across the room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution is to use custom RAII classes: a try/catch block with a rethrow is equivalent to a destructor doing the same clean-up although with two managable caveats (unless the exception type is used somehow):

- the object won't have the implicit context of the catch-block i.e. it needs to get the necessary information passed
- the destructor is always called, i.e. it is necessary to signal that it does need to do anything once the main operation succeeded

Since you didn't state what else you needed to clean-up I can't comment in how to best deal with this other than doing it in a destructor. For the allocator use I would actually create a custom smart pointer which takes the constructor arguments and the allocator as arguments to its own constructor (yes, with variadic and perfect forwarding unavailable this is a bit annoying but doable: I have done something like this more than once). The smart piinter would actually bundle up the allocator as well for also dealing with the deallocation later using the correct allocator. Since move semantics essentially can't be done right without rvalue references the smart pointer would use reference counting.

Generally, using RAII is the way for all kinds of implicit undoing, even independent of exception:!for any mon-trivial code eventually someone comes along andprematurely returns from the function. It may be a bit more up-front work to create RAII classes but I found that it dramatically releaves me from rather technical work mixed up with business logic. Also, many classes I have started their life as RAII classes but turned into classes encapsulating the functionality used to access the "resource's" logic.